# Add variable to URL in Locust test

Tags: python, variables, testing, request, locust

I'm been trying to figure out how to add a variable captured from a prior 'task' on Locust and add a variable to a new tasks `GET` request URL.

The variable below, `portid`, is suppose to go on the end of the get request: `/portfolios/portid`

**Example 1:**

```
@task
    def PortPage(self):
      get = self.client.get("/portfolios/" + portid, data=data, headers=header)
```

Error:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

**Example 2:**

I've also tried with a `%` sign because I read it has worked before but not for my instance..

```
@task
    def PortPage(self):
      get = self.client.get("/portfolios/" % portid, data=data, headers=header)
```

Error:

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Any assistance obviously appreciated.

Comment: flagged NAO's comment for spam - looks like an exploited account

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're just looking for normal string formatting!

```py
>>> portid = 100
>>> f"/portfolios/{portid}"
'/portfolios/100'
```

The issue is simply that Python doesn't guess when you attempt to add a number to a string what should happen!

You can choose from a few options according to your needs, though the f-string variant is probably preferable for your case

```py
>>> "/portfolios/" + portid          # fails with the error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
>>> "/portfolios/" + str(portid)     # effectively simplest
'/portfolios/100'
>>> f"/portfolios/{portid}"          # modern
'/portfolios/100'
>>> "/portfolios/{}".format(portid)  # obvious
'/portfolios/100'
>>> "/portfolios/%i" % portid        # considered old, will do some coercions
'/portfolios/100'
```

Comment: Appreciate all those examples!